# XSS mitigation in HTML/VBScript/Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic, xss

I'm faced with the following hypothetical XSS vulnerability in my web code:

original code: `<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME='acctno' VALUE='" &Session("acctno")& "'>`

hacked code: `<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME='acctno' VALUE='12345'/><script>alert(98765)</script>`

Can I mitigate this simply by adding `HTMLEncode` to the session variable in the value field?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly.  You need to HTML encode all text that gets inserted into the HTML.

You also need to Javascript-encode any text that gets inserted into Javascript code, and you need to URL-encode any text that gets inserted into URLs.

Comment: They should check the value isn't null before using HTMLEncode.

Comment: The placement of the HTMLEncode method is unimportant, correct? In other words, the account number can be encoded higher up in the page and not specifically inside the input tag?

Comment: Strings are strings, no matter where you create them.  Just make sure you know what's encoded where.